# Can't connect to internet on real phone (Android) but works on emulator

Tags: android

My app is working well on emulator, but when it's on real android phone (sony erricsson xperia, sony ericsson xperia mini) it can't connect to internet. Phone has active internet connection using EDGE/GPRS.

Here's the class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class get_string {


    public String response_p (String url)
    {


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response_str = null;
            try {
                response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                response_str="NOT";
            } catch (IOException e) {

                response_str="NOT";
            }

            return response_str;


    }

    public String response (String str)
    {
        String res="";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(str);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
            res=readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            res="NOT";
        }



         return res;



    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "",res="";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            res+=line;
        }

        return res;
    }




}
```

Same result for both `response()` and `response_p()`.

Here's the manifest file:

```
        </application>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   </manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: how you are accessing Internet from Phone ? via WiFi or GPRS ?

Comment: Do you know where exactly it's failing?  All of your failure cases return the string "NOT".  Why not log or return the specific reason?

Comment: so your SIM has GPRS Plan ? you have proper GPRS Settings ? do one thing, open www.stackoverflow.com on your phone browser, it this works that means your GPRS is working and problem is with your Code

Comment: @Android I can browse any site, google map and all other internet based services, but only my app can't connect to internet , though it works absolutely fine on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved both response() and response_p() to my default activity class and it worked!
I still don't know why but both functions worked perfectly in emulator and real phone.